# Library to generate class that has inline constructor in another assembly with random data?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

I'm receiving event notifications from web services that trigger event handlers with data regarding what triggered the event. I'm trying to test that once an event handler is called that `a`, `b` and `c` are all called with the proper values. This isn't possible without relying on the web service

My solution is to create converters that convert the `EventArgs` that are returned to my via the services library (Exchange Web Services) to something my dumb objects can understand *without* relying on third part services. My issue is that the `EventArgs` class given to my by the EWS library has an internal constructor so there's no easy way to generate an instance of it with random property values without much work with reflection.

For example, I have a simply interface:

```
public interface IConverter<TFrom, TTo>
{
    TTo Convert(TFrom from);
}
```

and a simple implementation:

```
public class NotificationEventArgsConverter : IConverter<NotificationEventArgs, NewNotification>
{
    public NewNotification Convert(NotificationEventArgs from)
    {
        return new NewNotification
                   {
                       ItemIds = from.Events.Cast<ItemEvent>().Select(x => x.ItemId.ToString())
                   };
    }
}
```

Question is how can I generate an instance of `NotificationEventArgs` with random values. Is there a library for this that I missed in my searches?

The entire goal of this is to emulate if I receive an instance of `NotificationEventArgs` with the following values then `NewNotification` should resemble `x`.

#### Edit

In the meantime I will simply use `typeof(T).GetConstructor()`.

Comment: Only internal, no protected constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/):

> AutoFixture makes it easier for developers to do Test-Driven Development by automating non-relevant Test Fixture Setup, allowing the Test Developer to focus on the essentials of each test case.

After doing some decompilation of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices and playing bit with reflection, you *can* do it for example like this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();

// retrieve internal FolderEvent(EventType, DateTime) ctor
// using FolderEvent class as NotificationEvent is abstract
var notificationEventCtor = typeof(FolderEvent).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    new Type[] { typeof(EventType), typeof(DateTime) },
    null
);

// generate 10 random events with some help of LINQ and AutoFixture
var trashData = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => new object[]
        {
            fixture.CreateAnonymous<EventType>(),
            fixture.CreateAnonymous<DateTime>() 
        })
    .Select(p => notificationEventCtor.Invoke(p))
    .Cast<NotificationEvent>()
    .ToList();
```

Code above will generate 10 `FolderEvents` in a list, ready to pass to `NotificationEventArgs` constructor (which is internal again, so same code applies):

```
var notificationEventArgsCtor = typeof(NotificationEventArgs).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    new Type[] 
    { 
        typeof(StreamingSubscription),
        typeof(IEnumerable<NotificationEvent>) 
    },
    null
);

var instance = notificationEventArgsCtor
    .Invoke(new object[] { null, trashData });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, AutoFixture can't create instances with an inline constructor.

Comment: @Nosila: hm.. it seems about right. I checked the code of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll and apparently majority of code you'll need to make it work is internal. AutoFixture won't help much, yet you can still utilize it (not that it's essential tho). See my edit for working example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PrivateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class (specifically these [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243386.aspx) [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243375.aspx)). It wraps all the reflection work for you and allows you to create objects with non-public constructors, as well as access non-public methods and properties of those objects. You can get the underlying objects via the [Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.target.aspx) property.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only select one answer. Using `PrivateObject` paired with `AutoFixture` . Thank you for letting me know about this.